# Updating custom post meta with ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax

This AJAX function gets called on a click:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'site/ajax.php',
            data: {id: $('section#single article input:last-of-type').attr('value'), cote: 'like'}
        }).done(function(html) {}
```

It passes the ID of the post (which is contained in a hidden input) for function get_post_meta() that is located in ajax.php. This is what AJAX.php looks like:

```
$cote = get_post_meta($_GET['id'], 'cote', true);
if($_GET['cote'] == 'like') {
    $newCote = $cote++;
    update_post_meta($_GET['id'], 'cote', $newCote);
} else {
    $newCote = $cote--;
    update_post_meta($_GET['id'], 'cote', $newCote);
}
```

It is suppose to update the custom post's "cote" field, but the problem is that function get_post_meta() is undefined in ajax.php. This is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_post_meta() in /home2/electro/public_html/beta... on line 2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you load a file directly none of the WordPress functions will work. That is why you should nearly always use the AJAX API. The [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) solves this problem. Everything loads in WordPress context.

You would wrap your processing PHP is a function:

```
function my_ajax_cb_wpse_108143() {
    $cote = get_post_meta($_POST['id'], 'cote', true);
    if($_POST['cote'] == 'like') {
        $newCote = $cote++;
        update_post_meta($_POST['id'], 'cote', $newCote);
    } else {
        $newCote = $cote--;
        update_post_meta($_POST['id'], 'cote', $newCote);
    }
}
```

Hook that into the AJAX system:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_update_pm', 'my_ajax_cb_wpse_108143');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_update_pm', 'my_ajax_cb_wpse_108143');
```

Submit your request to `http://site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and pass `my_update_pm` as an argument when the Javascript makes a request.

```
var data = {
    action: 'my_update_pm',
    id: jQuery('section#single article input:last-of-type').attr('value'), 
            cote: 'like'
};
jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    // whatever you need to do; maybe nothing
});
```

You can set `ajax_url` similarly to this from the Codex:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'index.php' != $hook ) return;  // Only applies to dashboard panel
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
    // in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => $email_nonce ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain this please:
Submit your request to http://site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and pass my_update_pm as an argument when the Javascript makes a request. -- What is admin-ajax.php?

Comment: Is it like an endpoint for the API?

Comment: [`admin-ajax.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) is a file used by the WordPress Core AJAX system. All AJAX API requests should submit to that address.