# Adding result from PHP function into an input field

Tags: functions

I have the following PHP code which is a template page for a wordpress site:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Calculator Form
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="grid_7 suffix_1 <?php echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ?>">
<FORM action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/function.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" style="width:200px;" />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Calculate" style="width:200px;" />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="result" VALUE="" disabled style="width:200px;" />
</FORM>
</div><!--#content-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For arguments sake, let's say that the function.php file looks like:

```
<?php 
    function calculate($value)
    {
        return $value / 1000;
}
calculate($_POST['inputbox']);
?>
```

I want to add the result of this function into the result field in the form.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376

Comment: I know some PHP, but I haven't worked with AJAX yet. If you could post the code I should use I will be very grateful.

Comment: Follow the link. I _have_ basically posted the code just swap out the PHP in the callback and make sure you Javascript adds data where you want it.

Comment: I think I'm almost there. Where do I add the add_action calls? In the template file, or the function file? The JavaScrit goes in the template file I assume?

Comment: All of the PHP would go in `functions.php` or in a plugin file. The Javascript would be in a `.js` file of your creation.