# Call to undefined add_action() in theme's functions.php

Tags: functions, actions

Once done validating a form with ajax, I use php within my functions.php to actually send the form.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$subject_line = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];


if (!empty($name) && !empty($lname) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) && !empty($subject_line) && !empty($message) ) {

    $to = 'email@domain.com';
    $from = $subject_line;
    $subject = $subject_line;
    $body1 = "First Name: " . $name .
        "\nLast name: " . $lname .
        "\nEmail: " . $email .
        "\nPhone Number: " . $phone .
        "\nMessage: " . $message;
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body1, 'From: ' . $email)) {
        print "Thank you, we will get back to you shortly.";
    }
}
```

When I add in the php to the functions.php, I get the fatal error Call to undefined add_action() in the theme's functions.php. Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: are you calling `functions.php` directly or are you using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: Calling it directly.

Comment: Then fix that and use the API.

Comment: [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376) should help explain the problem with accessing `functions.php` directly.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I'm still unsure of how to implement the AJAX API. What do I type where?

Answer (score 0):

register an ajax action for submitting email:

Note `handle_form` is the name of your action in this example

```
add_action('wp_ajax_handle_form','handle_form_submit_111605' );
```

also add this in order to make it work for non logged in users

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_form','handle_form_submit_111605' );
```

do validation and mail sending job in the callback function  handle_form_submit_111605

In `functions.php`

```
function handle_form_submit_111605() {

}
```

User simply jquey ajax to submit the form through ajax
In you js file

```
<script type="text/jaascript">

var submitdata =  myForm.serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'http://domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=handle_form',
      //action parameter is the same one you used while registering the ajax
  type: 'POST',
  data: submitData,
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
     if(data.status){
         // ...
     }
   }
 });
</script>
```

See more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Hi Dipesh,

   I'm assuming that I should be adding both add_action() to functions.php, but how does all of that communicate with validating the form? My jQuery is as follows
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loading").hide();
  $("#myform").validate({
   debug: false,
   rules: {
    input: "required"
   },
   messages: {
    input: "error message"
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#loading").show();
    $.post('<?php echo $our_url . '/functions.php'; ?>', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
  $('#results').html(data);
  $("#loading").hide();
    });
   }
  });
});`

Comment: Your code says you are making front-end validation, `add_action` has nothing to do with client side validation, but  yes, you can do server-side validation with php in the callback function registered with your ajax action.Besides, the whole idea behind using ajax was to actually submit the form without complete page reload

Comment: Can you explain it to me like I'm 5? I don't understand what you're suggesting sorry

Comment: Sure, please tell me what things have you done so far. I guess your form is ready and you have already validated before submitting the form, right?These are front-end or client-side stuffs( because these code run on the users browser). 
Next you need to submit the form to the server so that the message or whatever reaches to  its target receiver. and this  is called serverside stuff( because this code runs on the server). You may again need to make sure you have enough data like email and message to prevent errors,so you might need to validate serverside as well.