# Directing to functions.php the correct way

Tags: functions, forms, fatal-error

Right now I'm validating a form on one page, and then sending the results to functions.php to send the form via email. Right now I'm doing the following

`<?php $our_url = get_template_directory_uri();?>`

... and then calling on it later in ajax using
`$.post('<?php echo $our_url . '/functions.php'; ?>', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {`, which works. Kind of. When I submit the form I get the error Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in functions.php. What is the correct code that I should be using to call functions.php?

Comment: The answer is the same as [your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111605/call-to-undefined-add-action-in-themes-functions-php). You should not be loading `functions.php` directly. Period. Full-stop. It will never work that way, because you're loading a file outside of the context of WordPress. I posted a full working example of an AJAX function in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56349/4771). Read through there as well as the [AJAX API in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), update your question with your code if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you 'have' to do it this way, you should add the following line to the top of your above your include functions line:

```
require('/path/to/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php'); 
global $wpdb; // In case you need DB calls also
```

@milo is correct though and you should think of a better way of doing this...

Alternatively, you could look at Gravity Forms or Contact Form 7 plugins which both have in built validation and allow customisation.

Comment: Thank you TomC! I ended up using a different file other than functions.php, and needed this to grab additional information. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Please don't forget to select this as the best answer