# Creating a post from data returned from HTML form

Tags: posts, php, wpdb, wp-insert-post, post-content

I am trying to write a WordPress plugin and I have hit a bump.

**The Background:** I have some data in a mySQL DB that I am using (each row has a unique ID and some other information I have added). I am able to search the DB using

```
$heads = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}costumesdb WHERE location = 'head'", ARRAY_A);
```

And display some of the information to the user in a form using (this is one of 5 different drop-downs but they are all created in the same way)

```
<form id="createacostume" action= "admin-ajax.php" method="post">
Head: <select name="head">
<?php foreach ($heads as $head) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $head['id'] ?>"><?php echo $head['shopName'] . " - " . $head['pieceName'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit">
```

The script to submit the form data to the server is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ajax_url,
data: { action: 'my_action' , param: 'st1' }
}).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.response );
});
</script>
```

In my php file serverside is:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_ajax_action_function');
function my_ajax_action_function(){

$reponse = array();
if(!empty($_POST['param'])){
     $response['response'] = "I've get the param a its value is ".$_POST['param'].' and the plugin url is '.plugins_url();
} else {
     $response['response'] = "You didn't send the param";
}

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode($response);

exit();
```

**The Problem:** If I set action= "admin-ajax.php" in the form I get booted to the admin-ajax.php page with a "0" response.

How do I get data from a form in WordPress admin page and process it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ajax in plugin admin area?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112706/how-to-use-ajax-in-plugin-admin-area)

Comment: I'm not sure. I have looked over those questions but I am having trouble getting any examples to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out and re-wrote the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#createacostume').submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var aForm = jQuery(this);
        var bForm = aForm.serializeArray();
        bForm.push({name: 'action', value: 'myAjaxFunction'});
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: bForm,

            success: function(resp) {

                alert("Thank you for your post. We will review it and approve it shortly" + resp);

            },
            error: function( req, status, err ) {
                alert( 'something went wrong, Status: ' + status + ' and error: ' + err );
            }
        })

                .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        })
        ;
        return false;
    });
});
```

You have to push onto the form the ajax function you are calling.