# get_term_children returns WP_Error for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, children

What I'm working on is a ajax based dropdown option form which returns child terms based on the option selected.

When the option is selected, a function is fired using onchange, where the script grabs the term_id and taxonomy of the selected option, and sends both of those to the server.

The server side script I created accepts `$_POST`, I have verified that the variables are properly assigned by echoing them back to the client and checking the console logs.

```
<?php
//Include wordpress
require_once( 'wp-config.php' );
require_once( 'wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME , DB_HOST );

if (isset($_POST)){
    $taxID = $_POST[id];
    $taxType = $_POST[tx];
}
else {
    echo "Error: invalid data recieved. Please contact the site administrator.";
    die();
}

$termchildren = get_term_children( $taxID, $taxType );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxType );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxType ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
die();
?>
```

The goal of this script is to return some html that I can insert into another element.
 - The ID of the element causing issues is `4`, which contains a child with ID of `15`
 - The taxonomy of the element is `classifieds_categories`
 - Passing these values manually does not work either.
 - When I echo the `li` `a href` I get this error:
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in ...`

Does anyone have any suggestions? Because quite frankly I'm about to throw my laptop towards the nearest window at this point.

Comment: I don't suppose you've `var_dump`ed the WP_Error to see the contents?

Comment: I've tried, however I can't seem to get further as PHP crashes before then. I am getting this from the log: [link](http://pastebin.com/SL7Gnjs1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `get_term_link()` will return a `WP_Error` object if the term does not exist, you could try:

```
$termchildren = get_term_children( $taxID, $taxType );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxType );

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term->name, $taxType );

    if( ! is_wp_error( $term_link ) )    
         echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

so it looks like you are trying to echo the WP_Error object.

You could try to debug it with:

```
if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )    
    echo $term_link->get_error_message();
```

Comment: Here's the edits based on your answer: [link](http://pastebin.com/ZQxjLk9m) , which is returning: `<ul>Empty Term taxType: classifieds_categories taxID: 4</ul>`, I have the child Veterinarians with an ID of 15 that should be returned on this.

Comment: it might be helpful to check  `var_dump( $term );` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks birgire for that info, this lead me to the solution. I fixed it by passing intval($term->term_id) as the first parameter in get_term_link (i passed it through intval because it doesnt seem to like non-integer variables)

Comment: great to hear you solved it and thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Even though [you are doing AJAX wrong](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), that isn't your problem. The problem is this line:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME , DB_HOST );
```

But I don't see why you need either of these:

```
require_once( 'wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME , DB_HOST );
```

Try the code without those lines and it works, at least when I try.

[But please do AJAX right.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376)

Comment: Thanks for the resources, I will read them. However, removing those two lines of code does not seem to work.

Comment: Post all of your code then

Comment: Here's the part of the plugin responsible for displaying the data and including the js: [link](http://pastebin.com/2u3Nki94) , here's the js: [link](http://pastebin.com/iVzR56hU)