# How to use ajax_url in front end when using with theme?

Tags: theme-development, ajax, front-end

I'm trying to use ajax function to my theme. I think i can't just put the javascript code in my functions.php, i have to register it properly and enqueue it.

So i store the javascript file with `.js` extension and enqueue it from my themes js directory. Now `ajax_url` is only available globally in admin section not in front end.

To get the url we have to use `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>` for front end [Reference](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajaxurl-is-not-defined).

How can i use it in the file as it is a `js` file? Php can not be interpreted.

Is there any other way to define the ajax_url in my js file for front end.

OR should i include it in the header.php with no option?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376

Comment: Thanks i got it. can not the same concept used in wp_enqueue_script function itself? there we have depends argument, isn't? There can we specify the admin-ajax

Comment: Should i leave the question or should delete the question? My Issue is solved with the link you have provided @s_ha_dum

Comment: Your choice. I'll mark the question a duplicate though. Upvote the other answer if it helped.

Comment: +1. I didn't have enough reputation to give upvote. Thanks