# Absolute Path (ABSPATH) in WordPress is not working

Tags: plugins, paths

I am currently working on a small task that store a plugin information into database, but I have problem regarding to include the file that has the functions to run the query.

Here is the line that includes the file:

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');`

but I got the following when I run the code:

> **Warning:** `require_once(ABSPATHwp-admin/includes/upgrade.php)`: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `/home/najam/dev/project1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-insert.php` on **line 18**

I searched a lot but can't find anything useful or helpful.

#### EDIT

Here is my code:

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_form';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  rows int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  cols int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
);";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta( $sql );`
```

Comment: Where is this code?

Comment: `ABSPATH` does not appeared to be defined. Where are you using it?

Comment: You probably missed a trailing slash after the `ABSPATH` and before `wp-admin/`. Try this: `ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/`. And consider [this StackOverflow WP Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960180/abspath-or-file) also.

Comment: no success.. :( by trailing slash... @mayeenul

Comment: **What is the file `/wp-admin/admin-insert.php`?** This is not in the core. Are modifying the WordPress core?

Comment: **insert.php** file that I made myself, actually I am new to wordpress, I want to that is there any mistake that i am making? Actually I want to store a plugin form information in the database.

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam   no, no trailing slash required after ABSPATH. ABSPATH variable already contains trailing slash...

Comment: Just echo ABSPATH variable and get surity what it returns...

Comment: You shouldn't be making additions and changes inside the `wp-admin` folder unless you're contributing to WP Core. You should create a plugin ( it's easy, a PHP file with a comment at the top in the plugins folder ), and put your code in there, and use the AJAX API and the hooks system

Answer (score 3):

> `insert.php` file that I made myself, actually I am new to wordpress,
>   I want to that is there any mistake that i am making? Actually I want
>   to store a plugin form information in the database.

Your question is very light on detail but I suspect that the mistake you are making is loading a file in such a way as it loads outside the context of WordPress, or in such a way that only parts of WordPress get loaded.

The lack of detail in your question-- the near complete lack of context for the code-- makes it impossible to provide a solid answer but I am leaning toward suggesting that you need to run your code via the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (even if not strictly AJAX). Something like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376

If you want a better answer, ***you must*** write a better question. Please click the "edit" button under your question and add as much detail as you can, but keep it organized.

Comment: I'd be quite worried that a database table is being created inside an AJAX call fullstop

Answer (score 3):

there is a nice WordPress function that helps you anytime you don't want to check for missing "/" on your path.

`trailingslashit`

your example should be the recommended way written:

`require_once( trailingslashit( ABSPATH ) . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );`

using this function, you never have to put "/" in front of your "relative" path, as this function makes sure that "/" will be in case is missing.

this is why we have created that function in WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

`ABSPATH` will work you need to include wp-load file.
 `include '../../../wp-load.php';`

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the / but try a slash at the start of the /wp-admin

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
```

But did you check if /wp-admin/admin-insert.php file exists?

Is the ABSPATH defined? Add the following to check:

```
// Is ABSPATH defined?
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
die('-1');
```

Also, are you trying to run this without loading WP? Plus, you could try site_url() and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

ABSPATH should contain a trailing slash already.
You need to include your upgrade file from the main plugin's file.
Maybe you need to hook into 'plugins_loaded' action or 'init' and then call the upgrade method.