# Why isn't my plugin seeing other classes?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I've written some very simple code based off of this [tutorial by Harish Chouhan on the Plugins API](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/communicating-with-the-wordpressorg-plugin-api--wp-33069):

```
    /** Add Plugins API if not already existing */
if ( ! function_exists( 'plugins_api' ) )
    require_once( '../../wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php' );


/** Add Internationalization if not already existing */
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_locale' ) )
    require_once( '../../wp-includes/l10n.php' );

/** Prepare our query */
$call_api = plugins_api( 'plugin_information', array( 'slug' => 'custom-favicon' ) );

/** Check for Errors & Display the results */
if ( is_wp_error( $call_api ) ) {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $call_api->get_error_message(), true ) . '</pre>';

} else {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $call_api, true ) . '</pre>';

    if ( ! empty( $call_api->downloaded ) ) {

        echo '<p>Downloaded: ' . print_r( $call_api->downloaded, true ) . ' times.</p>';

    }

}
```

The problem I am encountering is that it doesn't seem to be aware of the built-in WordPress functions. Why? I looked at Hello Dolly and I don't see any includes there?

[Additional Details; I'm running this in Cloud 9 (c9.io) and the file is in the plugins directory, same as hello.php]

Comment: Which functions namely? Which precise errors are you getting?

Comment: @Rarst - Initially it was looking for plugins_api(), so I added the reference to plugin-install.php. Then it was looking for get_locale() so I added l10n.php. Now it is looking for is_multisite().

Errors look like:
 "Fatal error: Call to undefined function plugins_api() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/plugins/plugin_api_plus.php on line 25 Call Stack: 0.0004 247152 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/plugins/plugin_api_plus.php:0"

Comment: code should be hooked to run on an [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). WordPress isn't fully loaded when your plugin file is loaded.

Comment: @Milo - What if I just want to have a page that doesn't necessarily "hook" into anything in WP? e.g., is there a general hook I can call?

Comment: Use the AJAX-API, even if not technically AJAX: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376